# When does a map between abstract simplicial complexes induce a homotopy equivalence on their geometric realisations?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complex

Let $\left(X_i,S_i\right)$ for $i=1,2$ be abstract simplicial complexes where $X_i$ are the vertex sets and $S_i\in\mathcal P\left(X_i\right)$ are the sets of simplices. Let $F\colon X_1\to X_2$ be a map of abstract simplicial complexes (for any simplex $D\in S_1$ we have that the image $F\left(D\right)\in S_2$). Then is there a way to characterise (using only the simplicial complexes and $F$) when the induced map $\left\lvert F\right\rvert\colon\left\lvert\left(X_1,S_1\right)\right\rvert\to\left\lvert\left(X_2,S_2\right)\right\rvert$ is a homotopy equivalence?

If not, can it be done in the case where the $X_i$ and $F$ are induced from graphs $G_i$ and a graph morphisms $f$ by taking their clique complexes? In this case, I would like to detect if $\left\lvert F\right\rvert$ is a homotopy equivalence from just the graphs and $f$.

EDIT TO CLARIFY WHAT IS ALLOWED: Any process which can be done combinatorically to the simplicial complexes is allowed (such as barycentric subdivision).

Comment: Maybe I'm too tired: why is the answer to this not the definition of homotopy equivalence (which requires two maps, although I suppose you intend $F^{-1}$ to be your second map), where the compositions in either order give the appropriate identity map?

Comment: You can (using simplicial approximation of homotopies) but it does not mean that you should, since it will be quite ugly.

Comment: You probably want some version of homology Whitehead's theorem.

Comment: It is not clear what you intend to want to allow or avoid. If your question is, can it be done without invoking geometric realisation or even the notion of topological space, then the answer is yes: you can develop the homotopy theory of simplicial sets purely combinatorially. But it is not easy to extract a combinatorial definition of a weak homotopy equivalence from there.

Comment: @Zhen I know you can do it for simplicial sets. I was asking for abstract simplicial complexes.

Comment: @Eric it's because the realisation of $F$ may have a homotopy inverse (which may not be  $F^{-1}$) which may not be representable as the realisation of a map of simplicial complexes.

Comment: @Moishe I'm not sure how that helps. Can you elaborate?

Comment: An abstract simplicial complex can be realised as a simplicial set (if you have a linear ordering of the vertices). I am increasingly unclear about what you want to allow or not.

Comment: @ChetanVuppulury In a few days, unless somebody writes an answer.

Comment: Without any further clarification of what is and is not allowed (e.g. subdivision and other standard tools of simplicial complexes needed to formulate simplicial approximation), I'm voting to close.

Comment: @ChetanVuppulury You say you allow barycentric subdivision. Well, then the barycentric subdivision of a simplicial complex can be understood as a simplicial set in a functorial way. Now you have full access to the homotopy theory of simplicial sets, including a combinatorial characterisation of weak homotopy equivalences. What's your excuse for disallowing this?

Comment: I haven't seen this before, could you tell me the construction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an abstract simplicial complex $S$, the barycentric subdivision $S^\S$ as an abstract simplicial complex is the set of finite chains of elements of $S$.
Thus, unlike $S$, the elements of $S^\S$ are canonically ordered, so $S^\S$ canonically corresponds to a simplicial set.
More precisely, barycentric subdivision is a functor from the category of abstract simplicial complexes to the category of ordered abstract simplicial complexes, and there is a fully faithful functor from the category of ordered abstract simplicial complexes to category of simplicial sets, and all these functors are compatible with geometric realisation.

Thus, any and all facts about the geometry of simplicial sets can be transferred to abstract simplicial complexes.
(Of course, it is *not* just a a matter of replacing "simplicial set" with "abstract simplicial complex".
For example, there is a combinatorial characterisation of the morphisms of simplicial sets whose geometric realisation are homotopy equivalences.
(It is, admittedly, very complicated in general, and involves constructing auxiliary simplicial sets unless the morphism is a monomorphism.)
Or we could use Whitehead's theorem to reduce the problem to finding a combinatorial definition of the homotopy groups of a simplicial set (and the homomorphisms induced by a morphism of simplicial sets), which can in turn be solved using the simplicial approximation theorem.
Or perhaps something else still – the homotopy theory of simplicial sets is very well developed.

Restricting to clique complexes makes no difference if you consider barycentric subdivision to be a "free" operation.
This is because the barycentric subdivision functor is isomorphic to the composite of the clique complex functor and a certain functor from the category of abstract simplicial complexes to the category of graphs.
In other words, up to barycentric subdivision, every abstract simplicial complex is a clique complex.

---

In more detail:

**Definition.**
An **ordered abstract simplicial complex** is an abstract simplicial complex $S$ together with a linear ordering of each element of $S$, such that if $D' \subseteq D \in S$ (and $D' \in S$) then $D'$ has the ordering inherited from $D$.
(This does not imply that the vertex set of $S$ is linearly ordered, or even partially ordered!)

A morphism of ordered abstract simplicial complexes is a morphism of abstract simplicial complexes that is compatible with the linear orderings on each element.

**Proposition.**
Barycentric subdivision is a functor from the category of abstract simplicial complexes to the category of ordered abstract simplicial complexes.
It is compatible with geometric realisation in the sense that there is a natural isomorphism $\left| S \right| \cong \left| S^\S \right|$.

*Remark.*
The forgetful functor from the category of ordered abstract simplicial complexes to the category of abstract simplicial complexes is surjective on objects: given any abstract simplicial complex, there is a linear ordering of its vertices (by the axiom of choice), hence we may equip it with the structure of an ordered simplicial complex.
Unfortunately, morphisms of abstract simplicial complexes will not be compatible with these arbitrarily assigned orderings, so there is no hope of getting a left inverse for the forgetful functor.
The barycentric subdivision is the best we can do.

**Definition.**
Given an ordered abstract simplicial complex $S$, the **nerve of $S$** is the simplicial set $\mathrm{N} (S)$ defined as follows:

- An $n$-simplex of $\mathrm{N} (S)$ is an $(n + 1)$-tuple $(x_0, \ldots, x_n)$ such that $\{ x_0, \ldots, x_n \} \in S$ and $x_0 \le \cdots \le x_n$ (but not necessarily distinct) in the linear ordering of $\{ x_0, \ldots, x_n \}$.
- The $i$-th face operator deletes the $i$-th entry, i.e. the $i$-th face of  $(x_0, \ldots, x_n)$ is $(x_0, \ldots, x_{i-1}, x_{i+1}, \ldots x_n)$.
- The $i$-th degeneracy operator repeats the $i$-th entry, i.e. the $i$-th degeneration of $(x_0, \ldots, x_n)$ is $(x_0, \ldots, x_i, x_i, x \ldots, x_n)$.

**Proposition.**
The nerve construction is a functor from the category of ordered abstract simplicial complexes to the category of simplicial sets.
It is fully faithful, and it is compatible with geometric realisation in the sense that there is a natural isomorphism $\left| S \right| \cong \left| \mathrm{N} (S) \right|$.

*Remark.*
A simplicial set is concrete if every $n$-simplex is uniquely determined by the $(n + 1)$-tuple of its vertices.
The nerve of any ordered abstract simplicial complex is concrete, but concrete simplicial sets are slightly more general.
For instance, in a concrete simplicial set, it is possible that there are two distinct edges with the same endpoints, differing only in orientation; pictorially, $\bullet \leftrightarrows \bullet$.
Non-concrete simplicial sets are even more general – for example, it is possible to have an edge that is a loop; pictorially, $\circlearrowleft$.

**Proposition.**
Given an abstract simplicial complex $S$, let $\mathrm{G} (S)$ be the following graph:

- A vertex of $\mathrm{G} (S)$ is an element of $S$.
- Two vertices of $\mathrm{G} (S)$ are connected by an edge if, considered as elements of $S$, one is a subset of the other.

Then the clique complex of $\mathrm{G} (S)$ is the barycentric subdivision of $S$.